# How to ensure the order of messages in CQRS pattern

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I juggled a bit with [Greg Young's sample application](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r) and stumbled upon the problem in a multi-threadded environment that the order of messages in a bus might not be guaranteed or the processing of an event might not be completed before the next arrives.

Because of this, the ItemCreated message might occur after the ItemChangedSomething message, or at least the first message is not processed completely. This leads to problems in the "read side", because I want to update data that is not (yet) available.

How to go around this? (Assuming CQRS fits for the Domain Design case.)

Do I have to create a Saga or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: I think that the read model projections is usually single-threaded. Therefore, contention problems do not exist.

Comment: @plalx could you elaborate single-threaded?

Comment: I agree with @plaix: you could have *n* number of projections but each has to be single-threaded since events happen chronologically and, therefore, in a fixed sequence.  Multi-threading would not make sense in such a scenario as events related to a particular correlation id do not happen in parallel.

Comment: Delivery is usually in-order, but it may happen that the message bus is already receiving the messages from multiple threads out of order (e.g., read projections that consume messages from two independent event streams).

Comment: @EbenRoux As long as your single-threaded projection is autonomous (doesn't depend on data of other projections) you can run all projections in parallel like you are saying, but in practice is it more common to have a single processing thread for all projections or one per projection?

Comment: Since I am also still quite new at this I don't quite know if one would want to process events from more than one source, or even rely on data from other projections as those are probably not going to be events since we are dealing with the read side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should choose a messaging infrastructure that guarantees delivery of events in-order on a per-consumer basis, even if multiple threads are delivering in parallel to different consumers.  I.e., if you feed the events in order on the sending side, consumers will receive them in-order.

Then there are two basic approaches to handle this situation:

- *Infrastructure*: in a small CQRS application without distributed data storage, you can record a global and increasing unique id for each event.  Then make sure events are delivered by the messaging architecture in order of their id.  That will completely eliminate out-of-order event delivery.  Similarly you can record the time stamp of events and deliver them in order of their time stamp.  While this might cause race conditions for some cases, for most applications and use cases time stamp based ordering is sufficient (in particular, if `ItemCreated` and `ItemChanged` are based on human actions).
- *State machines*:  For larger (typically distributed) setups, you can use an explicit or implicit automata/state machine model to cope for out-of-order arrival of messages.  With a proper messaging infrastructure, you'll never receive `ItemCreated` and `ItemChanged` out of order if they originate from the same stream, but it might happen that events from two different sources (streams/aggregate roots) are consumed by some projection or saga in arbitrary order.  Since these events are independent, there usually is a way (think state machine) to keep the projections in a valid state for either order.

Comment: is "State Machines" here something like a Saga?

Comment: I meant state machines as in the basic computer science definition, as you can use the concept in both, sagas and read side projections.